# Word-Break Problem with Longtable and TexLive

Tags: miktex, longtable, texlive

I'm currently building a table and came across an issue with texlive. I was designing my tex-template on windows with MikTex and it rendered just fine. When I rendered it on Linux using TexLive, I get an ugly double line wrap. Any Idea how to get rid of that and make the TexLive output the same as the MikTex output?

See Column Foo in the example below.

MikTex output:
[image: MikTex output]

TexLive output:
[image: TexLive output]

Source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}


\small
\begin{longtable}{L{3.2cm}L{3.5cm}L{2.5cm}L{.8cm}L{2.5cm}L{3.7cm}}
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
& & & & & \\[-.5em]
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
\normalsize\textbf{Blah} & \normalsize\textbf{Blub} & \normalsize\textbf{Foo} & \normalsize\textbf{Bar} & \normalsize\textbf{Baz} & \normalsize\textbf{FooBarBaz} \\ [5pt]\midrule
\endhead    

Test & Test & Test-Test-Test-Test 123 & Test & Test & Test \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: update to a newer texlive. In texlive 2021 it works, the different output is in texlive 2019.

Comment: Ah okay. I was just using the distro default version, looking into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of \raggedright has changed. The newer version now changes also \finalhyphendemerits, and this means that tex no longer tries to avoid that the line before the last doesn't have an hyphen. You can correct the output in your older texlive with

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\finalhyphendemerits =0 \arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

Comment: so, not my fault

Comment: @DavidCarlisle definitly ;-)

Comment: Ok, this is faster than installing and maintaining a manual tex environment, when I'm only using it for automated generation of documents :D